# ElasticSearch RAM requirement

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We are thinking of using ElasticSearch to store log data with the following simple schema:

```
{
    "data" : {
        "properties" : {
            "date": {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
          "status": {"type" : "string"},
          "group": {"type" : "string"},
          "ip": {"type" : "string"},
          "username":{"type" : "string"},
          "category":{"type" : "string"},
          "url":{"type" : "string"}
        }
    }
}
```

We are estimating that we will have around a maximum of 5000 INSERT/s and a maximum of 100 million documents. Any idea if a 8GB of RAM will be enough to handle this? 
From what I can see on the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html), the typical server uses between 16-64GB but no information about INSERT/s.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You need to test this. This is not a definitive number, it depends on the use case, hardware you have, the data you want to index, bulk or indexing etc.

Comment: Check out doc_values, which, for not_analyzed values, will greatly reduce the heap footprint.